# Should I import System.Web.Mvc into an Orchard content part driver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I'm busy following a tutorial in the Orchard docs for adding a custom content part to the *User* content type. It uses a view model that declares a list used for a dropdown as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<SubscriptionPackageRecord> Packages { get; set; }
...
Packages = _userSubscriptionService.GetPackages()
```

where `GetPackages` is `IEnumerable<SubscriptionPackageRecord> GetPackages()`. Then, in the editor template, they use a somewhat clunky bit of code to populate a dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PackageId,
                  Model.Packages.Select(s => new SelectListItem {
                      Selected = s.Id == Model.PackageId,
                      Text = s.Name,
                      Value = s.Id
                  }),
                  "Choose a package...")
```

I would prefer to have the model's Packages property declared of type SelectList, and use a simple one line call to `DropDownListFor`, but I doubts about the goodness of practice creating the select list in a closer to business layer class, the content part driver. Would it be bad practice to import `System.Web.Mvc` into the driver class and create and assign a `SelectList`object there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SelectListItem being a purely UI-related entity, creating it in the view is the right thing to do. Here, we're transforming a view model for packages into the objects that the DropDownListFor method requires.

Moving the creation of the SelectListItems into the driver would be equivalent to moving view logic into the controller. It makes the driver make assumptions on how it's going to be rendered. What if you override that shape to use some other technology than HTML, or some fancy script-based UI element? What if there is more than one representation of that list?

Comment: I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: Yes. Maybe I should look at an HTML helper to abstract the dropdown creation out of the markup, but keep it specific to a particular representation of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Parts are already tied to Orchard so as far as keeping a pure business object, I don't think you're making it any more dependent.  If it's not feeling right, maybe just go with a separate model for this view?